# bash script to get files from a dir and compare them with another dir

Tags: linux, bash, centos, ls

suppose i have a Dir1 with only files *( t1.txt, t2.txt, t3.txt)*
how can i get a list of the files name only in a bash script that allows me to compare it to another list of files in Dir2 and find the missing files without using **rSync**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`diff -r --brief Dir1 Dir2`

will tell you the differences between two directories, including when one directory contains a file that the other one doesn't.  Incidentally, it will also tell you if Dir1 and Dir2 both contain a files with the same name, say *t1.txt*, but with different contents.  It won't print files that are the same between the two directories.